What are the nuances between 그렇다 and 그러다?
I was wondering if anyone could explain the nuances between 그렇다 and 그러다 when they have principles attached to them. In most cases, they end up having the same spelling and through context you can tell which one it is, but I have come across examples online where the 그래 for example is attributed to 그렇다 when it seems closer to 그러다. I might be overthinking all of this but I'd like to know if there is a clear distinction or not. There are other examples (like HowToStudyKorean) where everything is attributed to 그렇다 but I'm not sure if that's just the teacher's way of simplifying things.
A. 내일 공원에 같이 가고 싶어?
B. 그래. 같이 가
I would assume, because 그래 isn't just an agreement but an agreement to performing an action, that this is 그러다.
A. 이 물이 맛이 없어
B. 그럴까?
I would assume that the 그럴까 in the example above is saying something like "oh is that so?" so it's 그렇다 and the example below is saying "shall we do it?" so it's 그러다.
A. 집에 늦게 갈래?
B. 그럴까?
Is this the right way to think of these responses or are they all really just 그렇다? Or am I overthinking things?

그러다 - Verb 그렇다 - Adjective
I read one article about this:
https://www.joongang.co.kr/article/7547143#:~:text='%EA%B7%B8%EB%9F%AC%EB%8B%A4'%EB%8A%94%20'%EA%B7%B8%EB%A6%AC%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4,%EB%A1%9C%20%EC%93%B0%EB%A9%B4%20%ED%97%B7%EA%B0%88%EB%A6%AC%EB%8A%94%20%EC%9D%B4%EA%B0%80%20%EB%A7%8E%EB%8B%A4
1.
'그래'
the dictionary -> "해라할 자리에 쓴다"
yes, it is verb(해라). so it's from 그러다.
I am not expert about this. I guess "싶어" is adjective?
but 그래. 같이 가 is natural expression.
yes, this is "overthinking".
If you think this is not right. We could use "응. 같이 가고 싶어"
https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/5acf362843f94f6cb811d25f92f84491
2.
I want to correct second example.
A. 이 물 맛 없어
B. 그런가?
'맛 없어' might be an adjective. 그러한가? -> 그런가?
3.
갈래? is verb.
so it is 그러다.
'그러다' replaces verbs, while '그렇다' replaces adjectives.
그러다는 동사를, 그렇다는 형용사를 대체하는 말입니다.
why is your second example '그럴까?' awkward?
'-ㄹ까'는 미래의 의미가 있는 문맥에서 사용되어야 합니다.
'-ㄹ까' should be used in contexts that have a future meaning.
for example, - 내일 하늘은 파랄 거야. - 과연 그럴까?

Thank you for the article, it looks like exactly what I needed. If i'm understanding correctly, if the remark is predicated by an adjective, the response will also be an adjective? Is that how you differentiate 그래 from 그렇다 and 그래 from 그러다?

Yes, "그러다(동사)/그렇다(형용사)" replaces the preceding words. 그래 is 감탄사. I have revised the last part of the answer about '-ㄹ까'.

Oh I see! Thank you for clearing up the point about ㄹ까. So to reiterate 그럴까 will always be referring to something that might happen later but because my example is talking about the present/past, 그런가 or 그래 is more appropriate.
